# HLSL defined render states

Tags: hlsl, directx9

As described in this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/effect-states#render-states) you can define render states such as ZFunc inside of the HLSL shader. You can also set these from [application code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3ddevice9-setrenderstate). If you set the same state (e.g. ZFunc) in both application and HLSL, which one wins and gets used? Does it always use application over HLSL?

Answer (score 2):

**This article is specific to using HLSL with the [Effects Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/effects); it's not general to HLSL**.

The Effects Framework is a high-level software wrapper over the Direct3D 9 (in this case) API.  It has no functionality of it's own beyond ultimately making calls to the underlying Direct3D API, and providing some syntactic sugar over the API.

The documentation article I link describes how states specified using Effects interact with application states:

> When Begin is called, a stateblock is created and device state is saved (unless you specify otherwise). After a technique renders the passes that the application specifies to render, End is called to end the active technique. The effect system responds by automatically restoring the pipeline state that was captured in the state block (unless you choose to disable this save and restore functionality).

**It's important to realise that it's perfectly possible to use HLSL without using Effects** (in fact, one of the old DirectX SDK samples was named "HLSL without Effects" and demonstrated just that).  You would just use (D3D9) SetVertexShader, SetPixelShader, SetRenderState, etc calls in your program code instead.

It's also important to realise that specifying render states is not part oif core HLSL; it's part of Effects.  You cannot specify render states in HLSL outside of the Effects Framework.

Finally, Effects is deprecated and/or removed in newer versions of Direct3D.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I could not find an answer to my question. In the effect system you can still define render state either through application code using the [EffectStateManager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/id3dxeffectstatemanager) or in the HLSL effect file. If you do this for the same state in both application and effect file, which one wins?

Comment: @Mats391 - because Effects is just a wrapper around SetRenderState calls, it's the same as any other case: whichever was most recently set when your draw call is made.